# I am Buliding a Angular 5 Website. I have a Big Gallery of Images which are pulled from API

Tags: angular, angular5, share

I am Buliding a Angular 5 Website. I have a Big Gallery of Images which are pulled from API.  i want to have individual share buttons for each image. how can i do that. TIA

Comment: post your trying

Answer (score 0):

```
get all the images from api and store all the image in one variable, then use *ngFor to loop through all the images and display that button in that loop.
For example: 
 <div *ngFor="let image of templates; index as i" style="display: inline-block; margin: 1%">
                <div>
                    <img src="{{ image.imageUrl }}" style="width: 75px; height: 100px;">
                </div>
                <div>
                 // to display the name of image, 

                    <p>{{image.name}}</p>
                  // button on all images

                 <input type="button (onclick)="whatever()"></>
                </div>

            </div>
```